# UWP Package manifest StoreLogo asset error

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017, appxmanifest

I generated all the required assets for the package manifest but VS gives error on  the file `/StoreLogo.scale-100.png`.

[image]

If I hover the red cross:

> A mixture of images with and without the "scale" or "targetsize" qualifiers exists in this project for the logical name "Assets\StoreLogo.png". When a mixture exists, files without the qualifier will be ignored.

So I create a copy of the scale-100 file and simply name it to `StoreLogo.png` so the error that aborted the compilation is gone (and it compiles successfully) but but I still see the visual error in the package editor as you can see from the image.

Does anyone experienced the same? Is there a fix?

Comment: Alternate way to do this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterR.UWPVisualAssetsGenerator . And as shown in you screenshot create 50x50 100scale image and storelogo.png is not found so place it in that location

Comment: You could try closing Visual Studio, then deleting all the generated assets and then regenerating them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in your solution explorer. There would be two images of the same type `StoreLogo.png` and `StoreLogo.Scale100.png`. This generally causes the issue. There are different trouble shooting steps:

- Open solution explorer and delete all assets named `storeLogo` with all scales. And then re-add them using your visual assets tab from a different directory.
- Click on the cross where it's taking the path `Assets/StoreLogo.png` and once done, follow the above method to add store logos afresh.
- If all doesn't work, then this is what you do, a little time consuming but it'll fix it. You make a copy of all your package assets (all the logos basically from top to down). And remove them from your solution and delete it from the path as well. No create a new solution and use it's default images to replace the one's in your project. Now that you have your package assets reset-ed, now you again start of with the process of adding your assets just make sure you don't make any mistakes while adding (you'll know if it's a mistake if vs prompts you or shows a red cross).

That being said, the 3rd option is always the last one. Most probably either 1 or 2 would get you fixed.

Comment: Sort of, I had to delete the asset folder, recreate with different name and the changing it back to the original name. Very annoying

Comment: Yeah it's a pain that ways

Answer (score 1):

Edit your VS Project File "*.csproj" and remove the line under :

```
<ItemGroup> 
 <Compile Include="*" .../> *your res name
```

Reload project and Build, Done

> Use the Asset Generator of the Visual Asset Manager.  With the
>   "Recommended Scales" option, this will avoid extra files overhead

Cheers

Comment: this works better for me, just deleted those files under here and works like a charm !